# Сортировка ключей по умолчанию в словаре

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка, python-2.x, словарь

Встретилась с такой ситуацией в питоне 2: ключи в словаре, что изначально имели вид

```
['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'h7', 'h8', 'h9']
```

отсортировались в таком порядке по умолчанию: (привела на картинке)

Каким образом получился именно такой вид? Не могу понять, как так вообще получилось. я попыталась угадать структуру дерева, но логики нигде нет [image: Сортировка]

Comment: если это не orderedDict, то порядок может быть абсолютно произвольным

Answer (score 16, accepted):

До версии Python 3.6 порядок ключей в словаре никак не гарантировался. Т.е. при обращении к словарю вы можете получить ключи не в том порядке, в котором они заносились в словарь.

Начиная с Python 3.6 в `CPython` (самая распространенная реализация языка) порядок вставки сохраняется и соблюдается при обращении к словарю. Т.е. сохранение порядка гарантируется на уровне данной реализации, но не на уровне языка - в других реализациях такой гарантии нет

Начиная с Python 3.7 сохранение порядка вставки гарантируется на уровне языка Python, т.е. обязательно для всех реализаций.

PS [связанный вопрос в английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

---

**UPDATE:** Если быть точнее, то словари работают по-разному в разных версиях Python:

- Python 2.7 - ключи словаря возвращаются всегда в одном и том же порядке, но порядок обычно не соответсвовал порядку занесения в словарь. Основано на хеш-таблицах.
- Python 3.5 - ключи словаря возвращаются в случайном порядке. Т.е при двух последовательных обращениях порядок может быть разным.
- Python 3.6 - ключи словаря возвращаются в том порядке, в котором они вставлялись. (**для CPython реализации**)
- Python 3.7+ - ключи словаря возвращаются в том порядке, в котором они вставлялись. (**вне зависимости от реализации Python**)

PPS [подробнее об эволюции словарей в Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8#t=5m16s)

---

**Вывод:** если вы работает с Python версии < 3.7 и хотите гарантированный порядок обращения к ключам, используйте [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), начиная с Python 3.7 можно использовать "нативный" `dict`.